# C# multi task consumption of python stream

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I need to consume data from a python API. I am calling this from a C# Windows Form / System.Diagnostics.Process. This I know how to do.

To eliminate duplicate calls from the API and to leverage async/task from a Windows Form, I would like your suggestions on the async/multi threading approach to the following structure. Please excuse the pseudo code for simplicity.

```
WindowsFormEvent()

    (Get a List of Items from database, I know this one)
    (Process Items (ProcessItems) in List in an async/multi-threaded way to increase performance and keep UI responsive)

    for each (item in List)
    {
         (do Something)      (these are not dependent on each other and can preferably run 
                              at the same time. These is called from a windows.form object 
                              and we need to wait here to keep windows form responsive?)
    }

Something

    {
          (run a python process, utilize StreamReader() that gives us List<string> results.
 
          #iterate over results
          (fire off x number of (threads/Tasks) to process each <List>item in results)
                  (lets say fire of 20 and then when, once one is done fire off another 
                   until all are done)(total list might be 2000 items
     }
```

Obviously this is an Architecture question.  I am not expecting the exact code.  If you could provide a good outline of the methods/tasks/awaits structure to complete this logic, I would be thrilled and will write up the ultimate solution.  Unfortunately the API is not perfectly relational.